# Multiple foreach loop a possible performance issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to read the products from the backend service and display it in the `angular` front-end. I have declared an array of products, which contains the keys that are needed for the translation. I am matching based on the code returned by the backend service
The code works however I think its not an efficient way since I am using two for loops. Could somebody suggest a better approach

```
     products: Choice[];
  
   products1: Choice[] = [
          { label: 'common.base-metal', value: 'BASESPECIALITY' },
          { label: 'common.crop-nutrient', value: 'CROPNUTRIENT' },
          { label: 'common.iron-ore', value: 'IRONORE' },
          { label: 'common.metal-coal', value: 'METCOAL' },
          { label: 'common.precious-metals', value: 'PRECIOUS' },
          { label: 'common.shipping', value: 'SHIPPING' },
          { label: 'common.thermal-coal', value: 'THERMALCOAL' },
          { label: 'legal-forms.OTHER', value: 'other' }
  ];
    
    this.referenceStore
      .getReference('products')
      .pipe(
        first(),
        tap((products) => {
            products.forEach((pro) =>{
            this.products1.forEach((pro1) =>{
              if(pro.code === pro1.value){
                pro.name = pro1.label;
              }
            });
          });

          this.products = products.map((product) => ({ label: product.name, value: product.code }));;
          this.products.push({ label: 'Other', value: 'other' });
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Comment: Did you have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#alternative

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple code that will require only a single loop instead of nesting forEach loop you can try this.

```
let products1Map = {}
this.products1.forEach((pro1) => {
    products1Map[pro1.value] = pro1.name;
});

this.products = products.map((product) => ({
    label: products1Map[product.code] ? products1Map[product.code] : product.name,
    value: product.code
}));;
this.products.push({
label: 'Other',
value: 'other'
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the use of a Map?

https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/maps/

```
products1: Map<string, string> = new Map([
        ['BASESPECIALITY', 'common.base-metal'].....
    ]);
    
    this.referenceStore
      .getReference('products')
      .pipe(
        first(),
        tap((products) => {
          this.products = products.map((product) => ({ label: products1.get(product.code), value: product.code }));
          this.products.push({ label: 'Other', value: 'other' });
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
```

Comment: I am getting this for the product1 declaration Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [string, string]>): Map<string, string>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, string]>'

Comment: Can you paste here the code? It should work.